# Criteria with TempVars - but prompt user if tempvars is null

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a query in Access that uses TempVars such that when the query runs and the tempvars has been populated it uses that value, but that if it has not been populated it prompts the user for a date.
Here is what I'm trying as my query criteria at present and it's not working.

```
IIF(IsNull([TempVars]![Role_DT]), [TempVars]![Role_DT],[please enter the date to report])
```

Everytime I run the query even though TempVars is populated a dialog is presented to enter the date.

Is there away to do this?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

IIf always evaluates both truepart and falsepart

figures....

Comment: Since you're using VBA to set your TempVars, can you just pass a good value to the query (i.e. if currently Null, ask the user for value). Or just make a Function that will return a good value and reference that function in your query?

Comment: The reason I set about doing this was a query that I'd changed to use TempVars turned out to be used in a considerable number of places and it wasn't feasible to go around them all updating them to use TempVars.  I tried the user defined function route, unfortunately that didn't work either.  The query references SQL Server tables over and ODBC connection.  Using a user defined function ground the performance to a halt!  I eventually gave in and cloned the query so that my bit used a TempVars version of the query and the others continued to use the old prompt.

Comment: Yes, using a Function can sometimes add a big performance hit - depending on structure and rows involved. Now that you've mentioned SQL Server, there is another option that we used with good success. (1) Create a table on SS with the field you need; (2) have your VBA code prompt & save the value in that table; (3) have your query include that table with a join to the other data. Performance is great because all processing can occur on server side. Challenge is modifying queries, but that can be done via one-time VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way 'round for `IIf`:

```
IIf([TempVars]![Role_DT] Is Not Null, [TempVars]![Role_DT], [Please enter the date to report])
```

Comment: Unfortunately iif will still evaluate both sides and hence prompt the user.

Comment: Yes, any parameter must be resolved. You may have to create a custom function as @Wayne suggests.